# Save spreadsheet row data to PDF using Gdoc template using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I've exhausted all resources I'm aware of.  Watched several different tutorials and spent many hours trying to make this code work.

I'm trying to automatically create a PDF from a spreadsheet row.  I save copies of code at every successful run.  However, I can't figure out at which point i'm triggering this error:

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'makeCopy' of undefined (line 35, file "CreatePDF")*

I was able to run the CreatePDF function successfully when defining the variables with "let" but since trying to pull them from the spreadsheet with the function: createbulkpdfs I haven't been able to progress.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Line 35 noted below**

```
//doc id      1rFkh5AmLPNAJ7z1olWBvubn-6Oh8S8_my-AML1lU48I
//temp folder 12ZEXitbgdyOQJiC-pHvshgsBuNOKEKpj

//pdf folder 1eomwcc_UNJhFhvxcoWwamyJUterZtTaB

//let name = "Dan";
//let email = "daniel.sgalia@gmail.com";
//let cost = "100";
//let squarefeet = "2000";
//let flooringmaterial = "Wood";
//let roofingmaterial = "Standing Seam";
//let sidingmaterial = "Lap";
//let kitchencounter = "Granite";   



function createbulkpdfs(){

const docfile = DriveApp.getFileById("1rFkh5AmLPNAJ7z1olWBvubn-6Oh8S8_my-AML1lU48I");
const tempfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("12ZEXitbgdyOQJiC-pHvshgsBuNOKEKpj");
const pdffolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1eomwcc_UNJhFhvxcoWwamyJUterZtTaB");
const currentsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SFR Calculations");

const data = currentsheet.getRange(2, 1,currentsheet.getLastRow()-1,15).getValues();

data.forEach(row => {
  createPDF(row[0],email,cost,squarefeet,flooringmaterial,roofingmaterial,sidingmaterial,kitchencounter,pdfname,docfile,tempfolder,pdffolder)

});

}

function createPDF(name,email,cost,squarefeet,flooringmaterial,roofingmaterial,sidingmaterial,kitchencounter,pdfname,docfile,tempfolder,pdffolder) {

**LINE 35** const tempfile = docfile.makeCopy(tempfolder); 
const tempdocfile =DocumentApp.openById(tempfile.getId());
const body = tempdocfile.getBody();

body.replaceText("{Name}", name);
body.replaceText("{Email}", email);
body.replaceText("{Cost Estimate}", cost);
body.replaceText("{Square Feet}", squarefeet);
body.replaceText("{Flooring Material}", flooringmaterial);
body.replaceText("{Roofing Material}", roofingmaterial);
body.replaceText("{Siding Material}", sidingmaterial);
body.replaceText("{Kitchen Counter}", kitchencounter);

tempdocfile.saveAndClose();
const pdfcontentblob = tempfile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
pdffolder.createFile(pdfcontentblob).setName("pdfname");
tempfolder.removeFile(tempfile)


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you worked this out already, but I think the solution might be super simple...
Before you run the script, change it so you are running the function 'CreateBulkPDFs' **not** 'Create PDF'.

You have two functions in your script, you need to use the drop down at the top next to the Run button to ensure you are running the function 'CreateBulkPDFs'.
If you try to run 'Create PDF' the consts are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

That error would throw because something isn't defined properly.  At a glance it looks like because on line 35 you reference 'docfile' and 'tempfolder' which are not defined in the createPDF() function.  (They are defined in the previous function)

It's not clear to be why you have the two functions and why you need createPDF to reference the other one, but it appears if you defined 'docfile' and 'tempfolder' (or any var or const that is needed in that function) within createPDF() specifically then it should run.

This should technically answer you question of why the error is happening on that line currently, without going into the full scope of needs for your project.

Comment: Thanks for your input!  This is the first script i've ever written and i'm following a tutorial from YouTube.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9uU_KwGgzQ&t=1551s

I tried to define 'docfile' within createPDF() function.  But it now gives me and error stating it is already defined:  

SyntaxError: Identifier 'docfile' has already been declared (line 35, file "CreatePDF.gs")